# menu with only the icon for small screens with foundation

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

Is there an easy way to do the toggle responsive menu for small screens with only foundation framework without using special plugin like slicknav etc?
I tried the top-bar and dropdown classes, but it is not rather responsive

Comment: i found this: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html with click triggers, it should work

Comment: Did you get it figured out?